# C++: Program to find the largest prime factor of a number, what is wrong in my code?

Tags: c++

This should find the largest prime factor of a number.. but it isn't working..
The answer should be 6857, but it is returning 688543..

```
int isPrime(unsigned long int n)
{
    for(unsigned long int i=2;i*i<(n);i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long int num=600851475143;
    unsigned long int max=2, i=2;
    while(num!=1)
    {
        if(num%i==0 && isPrime(i))
        {
            max=i;
            num/=i;
            i--;
        }

        i++;
    }
    cout<<max;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Which compiler and OS? `600851475143` can easily be too large for a `long` on many platforms.

Comment: VS2012 warns on this: warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from '__int64' to 'unsigned long'

Comment: Do you get any warning when you compile the code?

Comment: I am using code::blocks with GNU GCC, on Windows 7.

Comment: No, I didn't get any warning..

Comment: Doesn't `return 0; break;` strike you as a bit odd?  How do you think the computer will ever get to `break;` if it has already returned from the function??

Comment: Isn't this from project Euler?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa: http://projecteuler.net/problem=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other issues, this will be a problem with large numbers:

```
for(unsigned long int i=2;i*i<(n);i++)
```

`i*i` for large numbers will overflow for an `unsigned long` (which appears to be 32-bits on the system you are compiling for).

You can fix it by switching it:

```
for (unsigned long int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); ++i)
```

As long as `n` didn't overflow, the `sqrt(n)` will be valid.  However, I would still suggest a switch to using `unsigned long long` if you are going to use numbers that get very close to the bounds for 32-bit integers.

Comment: It should also be `i <= sqrt(n)`. Unless you think 4 and 9 are prime.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long` is apparently 32 bit on your system, so `num` won't be `600851475143` but instead `600851475143 mod 1<<32` which is `3851020999`. `688543` is the largest prime factor of this number, so it appears that your algorithm works correctly at least.

Look up the maximum ranges for the types on your compiler/system combination, then pick an appropriate one.